# Rails 5: Unable to access my database while using Sidekiq scheduler with Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq

I am trying to make a method run every minute using the sidekiq scheduler. But when I try to execute the cron job, my database is not accessible.

This is my controller code

```
#product_controller.rb

require 'sidekiq-scheduler'

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def task
    Product.each do |product|
      product.price.push(get_price_from_link(product.flipkart_link))
      product.time.push(Time.now)
      product.save!
    end
  end

 private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:flipkart_link, :flipkart_id, :name, :category, :image_url, :max_price, :price, :available, :target_price, :user_id)
  end
end


#sidekiq.yml

:schedule:
  cron_task:
    cron: '0 * * * * *'   # Runs once per minute
  class: ProductsController
```

When I try to execute the cron job like this,

```
sidekiq -r ./app/controllers/products_controller.rb
```

I get an error saying

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController
/home/raghav/workspace/apps/Shotgun/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:262:in `boot_system'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:54:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

Is this error because of the Redis server? If so, how can I access my existing models and database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your sidekiq command:

```
sidekiq -r ./app/controllers/products_controller.rb
```

You can't directly require a specific controller like that since it doesn't know where the superclass is i.e. your controller doesn't explicitly require the `application_controller.rb` file, hence that error.

Sidekiq's usage states:

```
-r, --require [PATH|DIR] Location of Rails application with workers or file to require
```

This is suggesting you give it the directory where your Rails application is, not an individual controller. But, if you run the `sidekiq` command from the directory of your Rails app then:

**you do not need the -r option**

Simply run `sidekiq`

Comment: After debugging a bunch of errors after executing the statement, I have one last error saying

undefined method `relative_url_root=' for ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:Class

Comment: @raghav_vc It would be more helpful to start a new question with that error and code examples and to mark this question as closed or resolved.